# Cgroup one of the needed subsystems is not mounted

Tags: mount, 22.04, container, cgroup

I'm a web application developer. I am learning about container internals and Linux.

I was following the article [Complete Intro to Containers](https://btholt.github.io/complete-intro-to-containers/cgroups). When I ran the command `cgcreate -g cpu,memory,blkio,devices,freezer:./sandbox` inside the container, it didn't work. I also tried the same command outside the running docker container but no difference in Error.

The error is `cgcreate: can't create cgroup ./sandbox: Cgroup one of the needed subsystems is not mounted`.

I saw some online solutions where certain flags are used in grub configurations. But I want to know the reason for the error and how can we resolve this. I assume that applications like **Docker** might also use the same underlying implementations to get the desired result.

EDIT1: I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with 5.19.0-41-generic Kernel.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** So it will be easier to diagnose your issue, please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running.